# Is there any MySQL function to directly get 5 closest coordinates to a given coordinate from database?

Tags: mysql, coordinates

I am working with PHP and use MySQL for database. I need a way, to get 5 closest coordinates to a given coordinate from database, which is very fast and at least 80-90% accurate. I have researched a lot. I found havershine formula, spherical law of cosines, bounding square method to compare min and max latitude-longitude values with coordinate in database and other methods which use trigonometric math functions. But all these formulas take a long to return result in database with thousands of entries. Does MySQL provide any function to do it fast?

Comment: It helps if you show the tables you have unto now (providing the `DESCRIBE` resultset, for example). But at first you won't find a quite specific mysql function for your (common) issue.

Comment: @leonardo_assumpcao my table has latitude and longitude attributes. Others are not important.

Answer (score 0):

See [this similar question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/31629) on the GIS Stack site.  The performance of your ultimate solution will depend on how many targets are in the reference table you are searching and if you can limit the distance you are interested in (such as closest 5 within 30 miles).  I don't think you can reliably optimize the process; you need to calculate the distance for all coordinates in your reference table.

Comment: The link you posted does not answer my question. Because it asks to use trigonometric functions, which I don't want to as they are expensive to perform on each entry of table with thousands of entries.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think you can avoid the math.  But computers are fast these days; CPU time is rarely the bottleneck with things like this.  Good luck in any case.

Comment: Using these math functions it takes considerable time even for table with less than hundred entries. Any ways, thanks for the help.